# RegExp заменить часть выражения переменной

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как можно заменить выражение

```
> var regex = new RegExp(/.*Math*/)
```

чтобы вместо Math можно было подставить значение переменной, а сама конструкция осталось прежней.

Comment: так укажите стринговую переменную вместо выражения var regex = new RegExp(regValue), где regValue string

Comment: @Dude36 если я так делаю у меня получается такое выражение /\/.*Math*\//

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp('.*' + regexString + '*')` не так? Или я чего-то недопонимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем примере символы косой черты являются, как бы, указанием, что в них содержится регулярное выражение. Если Вам необходимо динамически создавать регулярное выражение, т.е. строку, то указывать эти косые черты не нужно.

```js
var RegexEscape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var regexString = "Math";
var regex = new RegExp('.*' + RegexEscape(regexString) + '*');
console.log(regex);
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Я ставил "/" перед регуляркой, в этом ошибка

Comment: Эм.. А кто экранировать строку будет перед вставкой в регулярку?

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил...

Comment: @XelaNimed, ага, вижу. `-\/` - лишнее.

Comment: @IvanVovk, кстати, а ты в курсе, что последняя звёздочка делает? Что-то вроде она там не к месту.

Comment: @Qwertiy по этой регулярке /.*Math*/ делается выборка из базы, принимает такой формат

Comment: @IvanVovk, с каких пор база умеет регулярки? В like не регулярка передаётся.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так не сказано же, какая база, может, там mongodb, в которой `$regex` вполне есть.

Comment: @Yaant все верно